# Motor PI regulator structure code

Tags: c, embedded, nucleo, pid-controller

I am actually working on a robot project base on freeRTOS. I faced some problems with PI controller which controls robot's wheels speed.

```
#define To 100 // 100 ms     
   #define Te 5  // 5 ms
   #define Kp 0.01
   #define Ti 10  //0.1*To
   #define Ki 0.05/10   //Te/ti

   void corrNum(int consigneVitesse) // takes speed as parameter 
   {
        int eL,eR = 0; errors left and right
         float cdeL = 0 ;
         float UpL = 0 ;
         int dutyL = 0 ;
         float cdeR = 0 ;
    float UpR = 0 ;
    int dutyR = 0 ;
    float UiL= 0 ;
    float UiR = 0 ;
    if(consigneVitesse)
    {
            tickL = quadEncoder_GetSpeedL();
            tickR = quadEncoder_GetSpeedR();
            eL = (int)(consigneVitesse - tickL);
            eR = (int)(consigneVitesse - tickR);
            UpL = Kp*eL ;
            UpR = Kp*eR ;
            UiL= UiL + Kp*Ki*eL ;
            UiR= UiR + Kp*Ki*eR ;
            UiL_prev = UiL ;
            UiR_prev = UiR ;
            cdeL = UpL + UiL ;
            cdeR = UpR + UiR ;
            dutyL = cdeL < 100 && cdeL > -100 ? (int)cdeL +100 : 200 ;
            dutyR = cdeR < 100 && cdeR > -100 ? (int)cdeR +100 : 200 ;
            motorLeft_SetDuty(dutyL);
            motorRight_SetDuty(dutyR);
            HAL_Delay(5); // sampling period 5 ms
            term_printf("MOTOR LEFT ::::::> CMD : %d SPEED : %d Err : %d    DUTY : %d\n\r",consigneVitesse,tickL,eL,dutyL`enter code here`);
            term_printf("MOTOR RIGHT ::::::> CMD : %d SPEED : %d Err : %d  DUTY : %d \n\r",consigneVitesse,tickR,eR,dutyR);;
            tickL = 0 ;
            tickR = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        motorLeft_SetDuty(100);
        motorRight_SetDuty(100);
    }


}`
```

The prblem is that when the error reaches 0.0 instead of being steady is starts oscillating .

Comment: Elaborate the situation you have encountered and what you have done.

Comment: Such cryptic variable names... this is very hard to read even if you know how a PI regulator works. What type is `tickL` etc? Overall your code has very sloppy typing, mixing int and float, and using int in the first place instead of stdint.h types.

Comment: You don't seem to save the integral part anywhere? If you don't save it between PI regulator calls, the regulator will never work. You should have something like `UiL = UiL_prev +  eL;`, assuming `eL` is the error.

Comment: PID loops have to be tuned.  If the gains are too high then they will oscillate.  They can also get flakey when they don't execute at predictable intervals, in effect that changes the gains.  Note that HAL_Delay *inside* the function is not encouraging.  Start with no Ki, increase Kp to minimize the error but without getting close to oscillating.  Then slowly increase Ki to get rid of static error, you should not need much for PWM motors.  Worth too checking the step response, if you get a lot of overshoot then Kd can help.  If you don't want to implement Kd then you have to lower Kp.

Comment: HAL_Delay() is not a FreeRTOS function.  It is likely implemented as a busy-loop and will prevent lower priority processes running during the delay.  Do not use the HAL functions where RTOS implementations exist if you want to benefit from the deterministic behaviour and efficient scheduling the RTOS can provide.  Using a delay at all is a bad idea - trigger a task loop from an RTOS timer instead.  Also read Tim Wescott's article ["PID Without a PhD"](https://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4211211/PID-without-a-PhD).

Comment: Putting a `printf` in the time critical loop is a particularly bad idea too - at 115200 bps, you can output only 57 characters in 5ms - your loop timing will be all over the place.

Comment: Your error signal is the difference between desired speed and motor position - that will never work.  Motor speed is the difference in position over time.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear how you are using FreeRTOS in this solution - there are no FreeRTOS calls in the fragment, and the non-RTOS `HAL_delay()` and the terminal output in the time critical control loop will not help - you can output only 57 characters in 5ms - you do not have time to output text.

Your error signal is calculated incorrectly the encoder provided relative position not speed; you have to calculate speed from change of position over time.

You should dedicate a task to the control loop and use RTOS timing to ensure efficient and accurate scheduling.  The task should run at sufficiently high priority relative to other tasks to ensure jitter free timing.

The following should be regarded as pseudo-code; I am not familiar with the FreeRTOS API, so the OS calls are not real, and I have not dealt with instantiating the task itself and and have not dealt with scaling and other subtleties for which you have not provided sufficient information - it is the suggested controller structure that you should take from this - not the actual code verbatim:

```
typedef enum
{
  LEFT = 0,
  RIGHT = 1
} tMotorId

volatile static struct
{
  float integral ;
  int speed ;
  int previous_position ;
} motor_ctrl_data[2] = {{0,0},{0,0}} ;

void setSpeed( tMotorId id, int speed )
{
  motor_ctrl_data[id] = speed ;
}

void motor_ctrl_task()
{
  // Configure RTOS time for 5ms update period
  OS_TIMER timer = creatTimer( 5 ) ;
  startTimer( timer ) ;

  // Get initial encoder counts
  motor_ctrl_data[LEFT].previous_position = getEncoder(LEFT) ;
  motor_ctrl_data[RIGHT].previous_position = getEncoder(RIGHT) ;

  // PI control loop
  for(;;)
  {
    // Loop update timer wait
    waitTimer( timer ) ;

    // For each motor
    for( int m = 0; m < 2; m++ )
    {
      // Calculate speed
      int speed = getEncoder[m] - motor_ctrl_data[m].previous_position ;

      // Calculate speed error
      int error = motor_ctrl_data[m].speed - speed[m] ;

      // Calculate error integral
      motor_ctrl_data[m].integral += error[m] ;

      motorDuty( LEFT, Kp * error +  Ki * motor_ctrl_data[m].integral ) ;
    }
  }
}
```

This does not on its own of course solve the oscillation, but is at least a controller structure capable of control given appropriate coefficients.  To tune the loop set Ki = 0 and increase Kp until the motor moves as fast as possible but without oscillation.  This will not get you to the target speed because on target the error will be zero, so Kp alone cannot work.  Then start to increase Ki until the target speed is met. With even a small Ki the target speed will eventually be met but the dynamic response will be laggy.  Too much and you will get overshoot or oscillation.

Depending on the dynamic response of the motor you may need other tweaks such as integral limiting or dead-band compensation.  You may even benefit from a differential term, but for simple speed controllers this is generally unnecessary and often hard to tune.

If you need to output debug data, have the loop write debug data to shared variables (in `motor_ctrl_data` for example if using the structure suggested above) and print them asynchronously from a lower priority task at a rate that the terminal output can sustain.

The article "[PID Without a PhD](http://www.wescottdesign.com/articles/pid/pidWithoutAPhd.pdf)" by Tim Wescott may be a useful read.

Comment: I cannot address problems with this answer if it is down-voted with no explanation.  Happy to improve it or explain any misunderstanding.  Leave a comment.